# QTablewidget drop without creating new rows

Tags: qt, qt4, qtablewidget, qt4.8

I have a QTableWidget and 1 column has only checkboxes, so for those items I have these flags:

```
/* create prototype for checkbox item */ 
checkItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
Qt::ItemFlags flags = checkItem->flags();
flags &= ~Qt::ItemIsEditable;
flags &= ~Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled;
flags &= ~Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled;
flags |= Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;
checkItem->setFlags(flags);
/**/
```

Ok that works... almost. I can't drop anything in those items, that's good. But now there can be dropped in between 2 cells, so there is a new row created.
How can I prevent that?
In the other columns where the cells are drop-enabled, I can only drop in the cells and not in between and that is good. Why is this behavior changed when the item is not drop-enabled?

Answer (score 0):

A fast hack using an event filter (could need some tweaks):

What you do this is ignore any drop on the checkbox column. So it should be enough to disable row creation.

```
bool yourWidget::eventFilter(QObject *a_object, QEvent *a_event) 
  {
  bool result = false;
  if ((a_object == table->viewport()) && (a_event->type() == QEvent::Drop)) 
  {
     QDropEvent *p_drop_event = static_cast<QDropEvent *>(a_event);
     QPoint pos = p_drop_event->pos();
     QModelIndex new_index = table->indexAt(pos);
     if (new_index.column() == YOUR COLUMN HERE)
     {
       // Ignore drop event
       p_drop_event->setDropAction(Qt::IgnoreAction);
       p_drop_event->accept();
       return true;
     }
     else
     {
       // Allow drop
       return false;
     }

  }
return QObject::eventFilter(a_object, a_event);
}
```

Info about eventFilters:

[Event Filters](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)